# Call Linq Expressions

Tags: c#, linq

I have a dictionary of expressions:

```
        private static Dictionary<string, Expression<Func<Client, string, decimal?>>> decimalEx;

        public static Dictionary<string, Expression<Func<Client, string, decimal?>>> DecimalEx
        {
            get
            {
                if (decimalEx == null)
                {
                    decimalEx =
                       new Dictionary<string, Expression<Func<Client, decimal?>>> 
                      {
                        { "First", (client) => [...] },
[...]
```

Then from an other expression (which is by the way a LinqKit expression), I would like to call them

```
  Expression<Func<Client, ClientFull>> qu =
                    (client) =>
first =  DecimalEx["First"].Invoke(client),
[...]
```

But I get this error: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpressionN' to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression'

But if I set the expression in a variable before, it works:

```
var proxy =  DecimalEx["First"];

Expression<Func<Client, ClientFull>> qu =
                    (client) =>
first =  proxy.Invoke(client),
[...]
```

Would it be possible to call the expression directly without having to use a variable ?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use query syntax, use method syntax:

```
var query = data.Select(calcFunction);
```

Comment: Edit: In fact I would like to call it from an other Expression (which is by the way a LinqKit Expression)

Comment: @user1756338 Then you should have asked about that instead, and described the situation you're actually in.  Until you do so, we can only answer the question you've actually asked.

Comment: @user1756338 No, you haven't.  Your question is still exactly what you had before.  You saying that you're in a different situation than what you've actually showed us doesn't really mean anything, nor is it showing us what your *actual* situation is.

Comment: I have tried to simplify my question, now I think it is clearer

Comment: You've cut out way too much of the code for us to have any idea what you're dong.  You aren't even shwoing the entirety of the statements.  You need to provide a reproducible example.